# How to listen to QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged signals directly in a QML file

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2, qapplication

I am running my Qt application on **Qt 5.9.3** on **Android** and **iOS**. I want to listen to [QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationStateChanged) directly on a QML file

**How** can I listen to application state changes on QML using connection without having to write any code to emit signals from my C++ classes.

I want to listen to `Qt::ApplicationState::ApplicationInactive` and `Qt::ApplicationState::ApplicationActive` events using a connection. **Using something like this in my QML file**.

```
Connections {
   target: something_but_what
   onApplicationStateChanged: {
     console.log("State changed", state)
   }
}
```

*How can I achieve this?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have [access to that functionality](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop) from the `Qt` object in QML:

```
  Connections {
    target: Qt.application
    onStateChanged: console.log(Qt.application.state)
  }
```